# Laravel returning associative array instead of an array of objects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently working on a Laravel API and wish to return some data as a JSON array. I am able successfully do it with most data, however one query returns an associative array instead of an array of the objects. [image]

Here, you can see if I return a list of all the records, or where the type is food, a normal array of objects is returned. This will then look like `[...]` when returned as JSON data.

The problem is, when I wish to return type of drink, Laravel wishes to return an associative array of objects which I do not wish for. This would make my json look like `{...}`

Why is this happening and what could I do to stop this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values

Or try doing this to this to your response

```
return response()->json([
    'prop' => $prop->values()->toArray()
]);
```

Comment: All that needs changing is adding `->values()` after the `where()` function. Thanks for answering!